# Beamer-titlepage-picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, titles

I'd like to be able to add tow picture before the title on the titlepage in Beamer as below:

[image]

i used this command `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{Picture}}` but i didn't  reach the goal

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{picture1}}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{picture2}}
\title{TITLE}
\subtitle{\textbf{Subtitle}}
\author{Author}
\institute{University }

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=orange,fg=white}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick oneliner solution would be to use the following:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\includegraphics[scale=.05]{lion} \hfill \includegraphics[scale=.05]{lion}}{}
```

So that you'd have something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\includegraphics[scale=.05]{lion} \hfill \includegraphics[scale=.05]{lion}}{}

\title{TITLE}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute{University}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=orange,fg=white}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need more customization that you can't get via the `addtobeamertemplate` macro, you should create your custom `title page` template. The `default` template can be found in the `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` and with the requested modification will look like this:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \includegraphics[scale=.05]{lion} \hfill \includegraphics[scale=.05]{lion} % new code
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother
```

With the appropriate changes you can add vertical space or reposition the pictures or whatever you like.

Comment: @Educ you're welcome! Of course you can use the `height` option instead of the `scale` option like in my MWE, I used `scale` because the lion is kind of a big one :)

Answer (score 3):

I often need to do this as well. Instead of using `\titlegraphic`, I usually use the following approach:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushleft
    \includegraphics{leftpicture}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushright
    \includegraphics{rightpicture}
  \end{columns}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

or even

```
\begin{frame}
  \hbox to \textwidth{
    \includegraphics{leftpicture}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics{rightpicture}
  }
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you control the size of the picture

Comment: @Educ You can of course use `\includegraphics[height=4cm]{...}` as you have done. I was just giving you an example.